# How to create a Android type lock screen in front of a YII web app

Tags: php, jquery, yii

Thanks in advance for any advice.

I am long time developer but new at web stuff so please forgive any ignorance.

I am trying to create a android type lock screen (where you move the mouse over blocks in the right order to create a password as such). After this it will reveal the login page of my yii application.

This is going to be for an box that we install at a client location to manage our stuff. So the client will only have http web access to it - not so worried about password sniffing etc.

I have a mockup of the lock screen and I have a basic yii app that defaults to the login screen if not authenticated. I assume I need to merge my mockup and the login page. Also not show my lock screen if user is authenticated even at the login screen.

Questions:

1. How do I securely pass the lock screen password to the backend for
   authentication (I was thinking POST method on button click)
2. How do I hide the lock screen when authenticated (decide in yii/php to see if use is authenticated)
3. Any better ideas gracefully accepted :-) 3.

**EDIT** Also would like a reset if user gets wrong password, what do you think another button / left click on grid?

Assume the sample login page created with yiic.

My sample lock screen

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <title></title>
   <style type="text/css">

.untouched {
   background: green;
}

.touched {
   background: blue;
}

.button {
   padding: 12px;
   height: 100px;
   width: 100px;
}
   </style>
   <script src="/jquery.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
   <table>
      <tr>
         <td id="1" class="button untouched"></td>
         <td id="2" class="button untouched"></td>
         <td id="3" class="button untouched"></td>
         <td id="4" class="button untouched"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td id="5" class="button untouched"></td>
         <td id="6" class="button untouched"></td>
         <td id="7" class="button untouched"></td>
         <td id="8" class="button untouched"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td id="9" class="button untouched"></td>
         <td id="10" class="button untouched"></td>
         <td id="11" class="button untouched"></td>
         <td id="12" class="button untouched"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td id="13" class="button untouched"></td>
         <td id="14" class="button untouched"></td>
         <td id="15" class="button untouched"></td>
         <td id="16" class="button untouched"></td>
      </tr>
   </table>
   <h1 id="password"></h1>
   <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
      });

      $(".untouched").mouseenter(function(){
         if($(this).hasClass("untouched"))
         {
            $("#password").text($("#password").text() + ' ' + $(this).attr("id"));
         }
         $(this).removeClass("untouched").addClass("touched");
      });
   </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. `POST` method is right way to authenticate user, never think about `GET` because username and password are going to be visible to anyone.
2. You can save a Session ID or something like that in `localStorage` (prefered) or cookie using javascript to know if the user authenticated and access the page API with AJAX, when the API throw error with a header `401 Unauthorized`, let's your app prompt the login page again.
3. You can see how OAuth based apps work if your app need interact with your server.

[Live Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/PpFrf/5)

Comment: Thanks for your answer but POST is just a visible as GET if traffic is compromised - I dont get it. Also any chance of some actual code examples?

Comment: @AdrianCornish The most secure way is use HTTPS, otherwise POST is more secure than GET because this way show the password in the URL.

Comment: I disagree - POST is no more secure than GET. And my real question was (badly written I admit) POST (by button press) vs ajax type request

Comment: Well, if you want to load pages and the login page is only a overlay DIV, the recommended way is use AJAX for that. And about security between POST and GET, you can read this: http://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-bearer-19#section-2

Comment: just to clarify, POST is "more secure" because the parameters won't be saved in the browser history like a GET request, but not secure in the sense that @Fong-WanChau originally posted. All data is still visible over the wire if the connection is insecure.